# AngularJS next/prev word

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to show to previous and next word, 
and when the current one is 'fuga' one please let the next one will be first one('hoge'), same thing when the current one is first one the prev should be last one from list - 'fuga'

could you help me? please

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/zeck/L8Snx/][1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what you're looking for.  Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L8Snx/37/

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <strong>Previous:</strong> {{getPrev().name}}
    <strong>Current:</strong> {{current.name}}
    <strong>Next:</strong> {{getNext().name}}
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$scope.getNext = function() {
    var i = $scope.getIndex($scope.current.index, 1);
  return $scope.dataSet[i];
};

$scope.getPrev = function() {
    var i = $scope.getIndex($scope.current.index, -1);
  return $scope.dataSet[i];
};
```

Comment: Thank You very much this is what I was looking for.
Thanks! :)